# Lemon pound cake that falls

Tags: baking

```
1 cup (120g) all-purpose flour
1 teaspoon baking powder
1/8 teaspoon salt
1/4 cup (56g) salted butter softened
1/4 cup (48g) shortening room temperature*
1 cup (200g) granulated sugar
2 large eggs preferably room temperature
2 tablespoons fresh lemon juice
1 teaspoon lemon zest this is the zest from about 1/3 of a lemon
1/4 cup milk preferably whole
```

This is recipe for the lemon pound cake I am making that falls.  I am using self rising flour instead of the AP.  Any ideas why it falls?  I have made it several times with the same results.  I did add 1/2 tsp baking soda this time thinking more leavening agent might help.  I also added a tsp of lemon extract.  Could that be the cause?

Comment: Can you please include the method you are using and ideally a photo or two of the result?

Comment: Are you using self-rising flour AND including the full amount of baking powder covered by the recipe?

Comment: Besides the answers in the linked questions, consider your expectations. There are people who observe the highest rise while the cake is in the oven and assume that it has to stay that way during and after the baking, like a balloon that has been inflated. This is not realistic; many cakes lose a bit of their max volume, similar to a souffle. Only consider it "collapsed" if the result is too dense to be eaten.